# Magento Cloud Docker + Xdebug + PhpStorm = Port 9001 busy

Tags: docker, phpstorm, magento2, xdebug

I have a Docker environment running.

To get Xdebug running, I followed the steps from this page:
https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-development-debug.html

When I try to switch on "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections", I get the error:

> Can't start listening for connections from 'xdebug': Port 9001 is busy

Does anybody know how to setup Magento in docker with Xdebug correctly?

EDIT:
The whole environment looks like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                              NAMES
19d92752c73a        magento/magento-cloud-docker-tls:latest-1.1          "/entrypoint.sh"         4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds                      0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp               mymagento_tls_1
b71dd39b46c3        magento/magento-cloud-docker-nginx:latest-1.1        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp        mymagento_web_1
311e04f363b3        magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.3-fpm-1.1         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds (health: starting)   9000/tcp                           mymagento_fpm_1
cbdf9246f3e9        magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.3-fpm-1.1         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   35 seconds ago      Up 33 seconds (healthy)           9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9001->9001/tcp   mymagento_fpm_xdebug_1
2f1b4f2f9e23        magento/magento-cloud-docker-elasticsearch:6.5-1.1   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   36 seconds ago      Up 35 seconds (healthy)           9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                 mymagento_elasticsearch_1
d818c0755f4c        mariadb:10.2                                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   36 seconds ago      Up 35 seconds (healthy)           0.0.0.0:32807->3306/tcp            mymagento_db_1
19e266fbb72a        redis:5.0                                            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   36 seconds ago      Up 35 seconds (healthy)           0.0.0.0:32806->6379/tcp            mymagento_redis_1
```

Comment: WHY do you use 9001 for Xdebug when the link you have referenced clearly uses **9002** for Xdebug? 9001 i used there for some php-fpm comms (not sure what that is needed for though -- perhaps for a web server to communicate to php-fpm...)

Comment: If you use `netstat` or similar toll that can show what programs are listening on what ports .. the 9001 will be already occupied, most likely by the Docker  (as per `ports:  - '9001:9001'` part). No surprise that 9001 is busy here as for me... P.S. If that `9001:9001` part is for Xdebug ... then it's just wrong/unnecessary.

Comment: @LazyOne The port 9002 is only an example how to change the config. The port is occupied by the docker container with the xdebug running.

Comment: @LazyOne So you think removing
ports:
      - '9001:9001'

in the config of the xdebug container would do the trick?

Comment: In such case specifying 9001 for Xdebug and having `ports:  - '9001:9001'` in Docker file at the same time is wrong. `9001:9001` tells: outside of the container (host OS in most cases), listen on first port (9001) for incoming connections and forward them inside the container to the second port (9001 as well). This means that first 9001 must be used by the Docker. And because it's already used by the Docker, then PhpStorm is unable to listen there.

Comment: You have to remember: it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around (a typical misconception of how Xdebug works). So yes -- removing these 2 lines `ports:  - '9001:9001'` quite possibly will resolve the "port is busy" issue. Use `netstat` or alike and see what program uses that port. If it's Docker/container -- then yes.

Comment: Or just use 9002 port (or any other free port) for Xdebug comms: on both PhpStorm and Docker/Xdebug config in php.ini (or how you pass Xdebug config for this image)

Comment: @LazyOne
If I understand you correctly, then I have to remove the ports from the container config. Then update the php.ini with a specific port (that is not used) and then use that port in PhpStorm debug settings. Correct?

Comment: Yes and No at the same time. You either change Xdebug port to be 9002 in PhpStorm and php.ini/Xdebug config (but do NOT touch 9001:9001 part) .. or just remove these 2 lines `ports:  - '9001:9001'` from Docker file config. As per your latest update (containers and what ports they are using -- `0.0.0.0:9001->9001/tcp   mymagento_fpm_xdebug_1` bit) the "port is busy" error is caused by that 9001:9001 line, which is not needed at all for Xdebug, unless it's used for something else).

Comment: Sure, you can do BOTH .. but if you get rid of 9001:9001 part ... then PhpStorm will be able to listen on 9001 port for incoming Xdebug connections and there will be no need to change it to use 9002 (or any other number).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed by adding the xdebug extension to the xdebug docker container config:

```
fpm_xdebug:
  environment:
      - 'PHP_EXTENSIONS=bcmath bz2 calendar exif gd gettext intl mysqli pcntl pdo_mysql soap sockets sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm opcache zip redis xsl blackfire sodium xdebug'
```

And by using the Port 9002 in the php.ini and in Phpstorm (Thanks @LazyOne).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the port issue, my Linux machine can't resolve `host.docker.internal` host, so I replaced it with IP-address `172.17.0.1`
(https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/7400).

You can check what is yours IP-address using a command:

```
$ docker run --rm alpine ip route | awk 'NR==1 {print $3}'
```

To avoid losing configuration by rewriting `docker-composer.yml` and `.docker/config.env` file (when you'll do next time `ece-docker build:compose command`), I decided to add new configuration to new `docker-compose.override.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '2.1'
    fpm_xdebug:
        environment:
            - 'PHP_EXTENSIONS=bcmath bz2 calendar exif gd gettext intl mysqli pcntl pdo_mysql soap sockets sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm opcache zip redis xsl sodium xdebug'
            - 'XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_host=172.17.0.1 remote_port=9002'
```

Then, set a new value of Xdebug listening port at PhpStorm: `9002`

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all remove comments from these lines in
   DockerFolder/bin/webserver/Dockerfile.yml

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.9.6
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

here you can see I have set version to 2.9.6, you do the same

2. Now add these lines in your Config/php/php.ini  file

   xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1/16

   xdebug.default_enable=1

   xdebug.remote_autostart=1

   xdebug.remote_connect_back=1

   xdebug.remote_enable=1

   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

   xdebug.remote_port=9000

   xdebug.idekey=VSCODE

   xdebug.extended_info=1

To find host mentioned in php.ini file changes first line
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1/16

Run below command

```
   ip a
```

you will find
172.17.0.1/16
or
172.27.0.1/16
something similar to it. Try them one by one.
Php.ini file will automatically take those changes when you do

```
 sudo docker-compose down -v && sudo docker-compse up -d
```

3. In your Vscode launch.json file add these configurations. These are the same as default configuration but just 3 new lines added.

   {
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
   {
   "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
   "type": "php",
   "request": "launch",
   "port": 9000,
   "pathMappings": {
   "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceFolder}",
   },
   },
   {
   "name": "Launch currently open script",
   "type": "php",
   "request": "launch",
   "program": "${file}",
   "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
   "port": 9000
   }
   ]
   }

Those 3 new lines are

```
 "pathMappings": {
                    "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceFolder}",
                },
```

4. This video will help
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mahIIF0c8Zo

I have also saved a docker_image which will automatically install xdebug along with other magento environment. May be you had to find xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1/16 , as described in step 2.